# FME: How to ged rid of overlapping polygons and keep only one

Tags: gis, fme

I am stuck with a problem related to FME and hope you can help me sort it out.

**Background:**
I am working with a Feature Class which consists of digitized polygons from different sources. Due to that many of these polygons exist more than one time.

**Problem:**
I want to get rid of the older ones (they all come with a date) and keep only the latest polygon.

**My solution:**
I applied the Spatial Relator, than added a ListSorter in order to sort by incoming date. A Tester, which comes right behind, tests if the incoming date is newer than this of the related canidates.
[image]

**The output:**
The derived Feature Class contains ALL polygons and not only the latest one.
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If by latest you want only that day's polygon then I would suggest using a TestFilter that tests the date attribute to whatever you want to pass.

e.g. [LEFT ATTRIBUTE] LIKE [VALUE OF RIGHT ATTRIBUTE]

Answer (score 0):

Use a Matcher on the feature class.
On the Matched port, sort descending by date using a Sorter. 
Then use a Sampler to Sample 1 of "first N features".